# Python Map apply same function name but different functions

Tags: python

So I want to apply a function to values using `map` where each function is dependent upon the value.

For example, in my problem, I have a list of objects where each have their own personalized function called `predict` and I want to apply each of these functions to the same input. How would I do this using `map`?

More specifically, I have different model objects where each model has their own specialized predict function that is not similar to the rest. For this list of different model objects, I want to apply their predict function to the same data set.

Simple Example:

```
class Model1:

    def predict(self, value):
        return value ** 1

class Model2:

    def predict(self, value):
        return value ** 2 + value / 3

class Model3:

    def predict(self, value):
        return value ** 3 * value

m1 = Model1
m2 = Model2
m3 = Model3
models = [m1, m2, m3]
data = [1,3,2,34]
result = map(models.predict, data) # how to do this step??
```

NOTE: I want to do this with the map function, I know how to do this without.

Comment: `[*map(f, inputs) for f in funcs]`? Not enough details right now.

Comment: "objects where each have their own personalized function"... do you mean they have methods? Or are these separate functions designed to be used on the objects? It's hard to tell exactly what you're getting at.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? As blorgon said, there isn't enough details to go off of. Can you give an expected output and what your attempt gave?

Comment: `[x.predict(inputs) for x in xs]`...?

Comment: *personalized function" - did you mean methods?

Comment: A personalized function means your own function definition (or lambda). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I would like to use map function as it can be parallelized by a library.

Comment: So.. you want to apply each predict method to each number in the data? So in this case, you'd get twelve total numbers? And are these supposed to be static methods? You never create instances of your classes, nor do the methods refer to any attributes of `self`.

Comment: The example still doesn't clear it up completely.... How do you know which number of `data` should the predict function be applied to

Comment: BTW, you can't call `.predict()` on a list....

Comment: How do you know which model to use for each value?

Comment: Is there more logic we're not seeing here? Because `value ** 1` is just `value`. And `value ** 3 * value` is `value ** 4`, as long as your inputs are numbers, as shown.

Comment: `map(lambda x: x.predict(inputs), models)`

Comment: Which library would "parallelize" the `map`? And why wouldn't it work on a generator comprehension?

Comment: Can you write out how you would do it without the `map`?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are after:

```py
result = [map(model.predict, data) for model in models]
```

Note that this will give you a list of `map objects`, each being an iterable of the predictions for a given model. But not a list.

If you wanted a list of lists then you can either:

```py
result = [list(map(model.predict, data)) for model in models]
```

Or why even bother with the map:

```py
result = [[model.predict(dat) for dat in data] for model in models]
```

And if you want a single flat list, why not:

```py
result = [model.predict(dat) for model in models for dat in data]
```

etc etc..